# What is the meaning of angle bracket in the declaration of a function as a friend?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, friend-function, function-templates

I have a hard time understanding the notation `<>` in the declaration of a function as a friend. (This is originated by needing to define the body of a function that was an injected friend into an external free function.)

```
template<class T> class A;

template<class T> double f(A<T> const& a);

template<class T>
class A{
    double p_;
    friend double f<>(A<T> const& a); // same as friend double f<>(A const& a);
};
```

**Is this exactly equivalent to `friend double f<T>(A<T> const& a);`?
If so, what is the purpose of this notation `<>`? After all `f` doesn't have default template parameters.**

Is it the case that more generally:

```
template<class T1, class T2, ...>
class A{
    double p_;
    friend double f<>(A const& a); // same as double f<T1, T2, ...>?
};
```

?

Answer (score 4):

It is the same as `friend double f<T>(A<T> const&)`. You would normally use the empty template arguments to disambiguate between a function non-template `f` and a function template `f`. If you did not have `<>` the compiler would've created an entirely separate non-template function `f` and the other `f<T>` would not be able to access private members.

```
template<class T> class A;
template<class T> double f(A<T> const& a);
template<class T>
class A {
  double p_;
  friend double f(A<T> const& a); // notice omission of <>, declared as non-template
};

template<class T>
double f(A<T> const& a) {
  return a.p_;
}

int main() {
  f<>( A<int>{} ); // 'double A<int>::p_' is private within this context
}
```

> Is is [sic] the case that more generally:
>
> ```
> template<class T1, class T2, ...>
> class A{
>     double p_;
>     friend double f<>(A const& a); // same as double f<T1, T2, ...>?
> };
> ```

If, for instance, `f` is declared outside the class as `template<class...Ts>f(A<Ts...>);` then yes, they are equivalent.

Comment: ... and if not, then it tries to deduce what goes in inside the `<>`?

Comment: @alfC If `f` has all default template arguments or the template parameters are deduced through template argument deduction, then yes it deduces what goes inside `<>` from the parameter list of the friend declaration.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases when the name of a template is used, the compiler needs to determine what the template arguments are, which determines the exact specialization of a template it represents.

It sounds like you're familiar with how this is done for class templates (ignoring template parameter packs for simplicity):

1. Each argument within the `<>` is one of the template arguments, in order from the beginning.
2. If the template has more template parameters than there are arguments within the `<>`, default template arguments are used for the remaining positions (and those default template arguments must exist).

But for function templates, there's a third possibility, of automatically deducing template arguments.  You might be familiar with the idea of deducing template arguments from a call to a function template in a form like `func(a1, a2)`.  But deduction is also possible in a form like `func<x1, x2>(a1, a2)`, and can mix and match with the other sources of template arguments (again ignoring template parameter packs):

1. Each argument within the `<>` is one of the template arguments, in order from the beginning.  These are substituted for the corresponding template parameters everywhere in the function type before moving on to the next step.
2. Any remaining template parameters can be deduced (from the types of argument expressions in a call, or from the declared parameter types when matching declarations in cases like this `friend` usage).
3. For any remaining template parameters not explicitly specified and not deduced, a default template argument can be used.  (C++11 and later only - C++03 did not allow function templates to have default template arguments at all.)

So in the case of a function call, it's valid to use `func<>(a1, a2)`, which means all the template arguments are to be either deduced from the types of `a1` and `a2` or else taken from a default template argument.  This is mostly the same as just `func(a1, a2)`, except that for `func(a1, a2)`, overload resolution might select a non-template function which is also named `func`; but using `func<>(a1, a2)`, only templates are eligible for consideration.

Similarly, a template argument list can be needed in a friend declaration to make sure the compiler knows it names a specialization of a function template, and not a plain non-template function.  Again, often an empty list `<>` will do, assuming all the template arguments can be deduced from the function parameter types.  Note the differences here:

```
template <class T> class A;

template <class X> void f1(A<X>);
template <class X> void f2(A<X>);
template <class X> void f3(A<X>);
template <class X> void f4(A<X>);

template <class T>
class A {
    // For each class type A<T>, declares just the one specialization f1<T>
    // to be a friend.  So f1<int>(A<int>) is a friend of A<int>, but is not
    // a friend of A<double>.
    friend void f1<T>(A<T>);

    // Exactly the same (but for f2<T>).
    // A is the "injected class name" typedef for A<T>.
    // The argument for f2's X is deduced to be X=T.
    friend void f2<>(A);

    // Declares ALL specializations of f3 to be friends of all specializations of A.
    template <class U>
    friend void f3(A<U>);

    // Declares a non-template function.  Each class type A<T> declares
    // a different function unrelated to the template f4 above or to
    // the f4 declared by other A<U> types.  You could define the
    // individual overloaded functions void f4(A<int>), void f4(A<double>),
    // etc., but only one at a time, and only if you know all the
    // possible types to be used!
    friend void f4(A);
};
```

> Is it the case that more generally:
>
> ```
> template<class T1, class T2, ...>
> class A{
>     double p_;
>     friend double f<>(A const& a); // same as double f<T1, T2, ...>?
> };
> ```
>
> ?

Possibly. Though it's not just a matter of taking the template arguments directly from the enclosing class template specialization being instantiated. Template argument deduction can get fancier. For example, if we have

```
template <class T1, class T2> class A;

template <class X>
double f(A<X, X> const& a);   // #1
template <class X>
double f(A<X, X*> const& a);  // #2
template <class X, class Y>
double f(A<X, Y> const& a);   // #3

template <class T1, class T2>
class A {
    friend double f<>(A const&);
};
```

then which template declaration matches will actually be different for different specializations of `A`!  The function `double f<int>(A<int, int> const&)` from template #1 is a friend of `A<int, int>`, the function `double f<int>(A<int, int*> const&)` from template #2 is a friend of `A<int, int*>`, and the function `double f<int*, int>(A<int*, int> const&)` from template #3 is a friend of `A<int*, int>`.  No other template specializations are friends of those three specializations of `A`.